# What is the difference between using Action.async and WS

Tags: playframework-2.6

I suppose both `Action.async` and `WS` (for web services) in Play Framework are based on `HTTP` and are used to receive `HTTP` requests and send `HTTP` responses. Both I suppose are asynchronous and can accept/reply `JSON`. `Action.async` could probably send back `HTML` as well in Response.

So are the two interchangeable if I want to create a micro-service (or a REST API)? Could I use either of them? I saw an example in which a `user` was added using `Action` but the list of `user`’s friends was retrieved using `WS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Play documentation, it seems WS should be used when calling a HTTP from within the play application. Not sure why though.

‘Sometimes we would like to call other HTTP services from within a Play application. Play supports this via its WS library, which provides a way to make asynchronous HTTP calls through a WSClient instance.’